# test the presence of items in a list and return item or index

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know how to test the presence of multiple items in a list and return an associated item or index

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function AlertDialog() {
  function createData(name, weight, id) {
    return { name, weight, id };
  }

  const [id, setid] = useState(null);

  const rows = [
    createData("Frozen yoghurt", 200, 0),
    createData("Frozen yoghurt", 500, 1),
    createData("Eclair", 60, 2),
    createData("Cupcake", 30, 3)
  ];

  // return id
  const funct = () => {
    // rows.map((item) => (item.name === "Frozen yoghurt", item.weight === 500));
  };

  return <div>{funct()}</div>;
}
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-9gfdd?file=/demo.js:0-580)

Comment: Instead of putting just a link to the codesandbox, please add relevant codes here

Comment: hello, i edit my post and added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be simply solved by using `findIndex`. It will return the index of the item matching to the conditions. If it doesn't exist, it will return `-1`.

If you want to have the item instead of its index, you can use the `find` method.

To get all items matching to the conditions, you can use the `filter` with the `map`.

**1. For getting the index:**

```js
const funct = () => {
    return rows.findIndex((item) => item.name === "Frozen yoghurt" && item.weight === 500);
};

return <div>{funct()}</div>;
```

**2. For getting the item:**

```js
const funct = () => {
    const item = rows.find((item) => item.name === "Frozen yoghurt" && item.weight === 500);
    return item ? <span>{item.id} - {item.name} - {item.weight}</span> : '';
};

return <div>{funct()}</div>;
```

**3. For getting multiple items:**

```js
const funct = () => {
    return rows.filter((item) => item.name === "Frozen yoghurt")
        .map(item => (<div>{item.id} - {item.name} - {item.weight}</div>));
};

return <div>{funct()}</div>;
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your help,actually your code is simpler

Answer (score 0):

to

- test multiple items: check the length
- get an item: use filter
- get an index

relevant JS:

```
  // return id
  const funct = () => {
    // console.log(item.name === "Frozen yoghurt", item.weight === 500);
    // check length
    return rows && rows.length > 0
      ? rows
          // case of item
          .filter(
            (item) => item.name === "Frozen yoghurt" || item.weight === 500
          )
          // case of index
          .filter((item, index) => index === 1)
          .map((item) => (
            <li>
              {item.name} - {item.weight} - {item.id}
            </li>
          ))
      : null;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {rows && rows.length > 0 ? (
        <ul>
          <li>
            <b>Name - Weight - ID</b>
          </li>
          {funct()}
        </ul>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
```

forked and [updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-70xty?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Hello,  thank for your help, the @yash's code is simpler.